# Why the question author is totally blank?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, users

[What are "." and ".." in a directory?](https://superuser.com/questions/37449/what-is-and-in-a-directory)

[image: screenshot]

It shows no question owner, not even a simple name (without link).

What happened?

Comment: +1 for Freehand Questionmark

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would expect that it was an anonymous unregistered user (which don't actually appear to have names - the "user123456" is invented) that got deleted (inactivity, choice, abuse - who knows). It happens; there simply isn't anything useful left to display there.

IIRC *ages* ago [a process was added](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/02/when-is-an-account-abandoned/) to kill abandoned zero-value accounts.

Re one of the comments about ♦ mods deleting a user and then undeleting the post - even if a ♦ mod *did* delete the user account, that doesn't necessarily take the post with it. That is usually reserved for spammers etc.

Answer (score 3):

Check out [this query](http://odata.stackexchange.com/superuser/q/1053). Both the OwnerDisplayName and OwnerUserId are null.

Either the owner was deleted inappropriately or something else happened to corrupt the data.

Comment: Indeed. Thank you for the query.

Comment: @Gnoupi: unfortunately, I think I may be wrong. I ran [this query](http://cloudexchange.cloudapp.net/superuser/q/1063) to find all questions that fit the same description (I even added LastEditUserId, just in case, which filtered about 500 out), but none of the random questions I've checked display as this one does. Apparently cloudexchange doesn't expose *all* of the data.

Comment: Hmm... in every one of the random questions I've checked out, they've all been *migrated* questions. And yet the user name is displayed. There's obviously something I'm missing here.

Comment: Could this happen if a user is deleted(and all their posts) by a diamond moderator and then 10k users vote to undelete it?

Comment: @Earlz: Do you mean that the 10k users undelete the post that had been previously deleted as part of a user deletion? Even if a diamond mod chose to delete every post of a user (which I doubt has actually happened) one would think they'd lock the posts they're deleting.

Comment: @Randolpho well you never know though.

Comment: @Earlz: true. It's a possibility. But I think my initial diagnosis is wrong anyway.