# Deleted users who created a synonym are listed as "anon" in the tag synonyms list

Tags: feature-request, tags, design, tag-synonyms, deleted-accounts

While browsing the [list of tag synonyms on Mathematics Meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms) I came across the synonym [vote-to-close] -> [closing] in which the creator is listed as "anon" — the username is not hyperlinked, just like how the user IDs of deleted users are listed in other places like in the list of close voters of a question, etc.

[image: Tag synonyms list on Mathematics Meta showing the supposedly deleted user "anon" as the creator of the synonym [vote-to-close] -> [closing].]

If this really were a deleted user, then I would have expected their user ID to be shown, and not "anon". So, I checked using [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.math/query/1178483/data-about-a-tag-synonym) for data on the tag synonym. And sure enough, it shows that the deleted user with the ID 147263 created the synonym.

To double-check, I looked up the [list of tag synonyms on Literature SE](https://literature.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms?tab=Creator&dir=Ascending&filter=Active) and came across a bunch of synonyms created by "anon". Checking with [the SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/literature/query/1178483/data-about-a-tag-synonym), these were all created by the now deleted user with the ID 80. Similarly, in the [list of tag synonyms here on Meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms?tab=Creator&dir=Ascending&filter=Active) there are several created by "anon", but [the SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1178483/data-about-a-tag-synonym) says that these were created by the now deleted user with the ID 54262.

---

**Feature request:** Show the user ID of the tag creator under the "Creator" column in the list of tag synonyms if the user is deleted, to be consistent with how posts and actions by deleted users are attributed everywhere else.

Comment: Found something interesting:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826782/how-to-disable-text-selection-highlighting?rq=1.  See who posted it.

Comment: @Ollie I believe that in that case the original question author requested to have that post dissociated from their account, based on [Donald Duck’s answer to ‘Why are some usernames on comments not a link to user profiles?’](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/290627).