# Cannot swap synonyms if creator is gone ("anon")

Tags: bug, moderator-tools, tag-synonyms, deleted-accounts

On German Language, where I am a moderator, I wanted to swap the tag synonym *determiner → determiners* (and then delete the plural variant) in the tag-synonyms interface. When I try to do that, I consistently get a pop-up:

> An error occurred; please try again later

I can swap other synonyms, so this is not due to the tag database being out of order or similar. However, what does separate this synonym from others is that its creator is [“anon”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/352892/255554), i.e., the creator of the synonym has since then deleted their account. I tested this with another tag created by “anon” and encountered the same problem.

With another tag that suffered from the same problem (I didn’t check for the creator), I could delete the synonym and then rename the tag, so there is a work-around. It’s just direct swapping that doesn’t work.

Comment: Side question - in my experience, the plural is the preferred tag (see the plural tags on this question) while this seems like an honest bug we should investigate, is there a need to use the singular here?

Comment: @Catija: There is no pressing need, but the vast majority of our tags was already singular and singular tags make certain things with tags with German labels easier.